# WebStorm: Initializer type <TYPE> is not assignable to variable type <LIBRARY>.<TYPE>

Tags: javascript, webstorm

I have a Vue.js project without TypeScript.

If I import some library with the `* as` syntax, the autocomplete / suggestions do not work.

```
import * as THREE from 'three';
const scene = new THREE.Scene();
```

WebStorm complains saying

> Initializer type Scene is not assignable to variable type THREE.Scene

Of course at runtime there are no errors.

What can I do to teach WebStorm to correctly assign the variable type?

Comment: can't see type mismatch errors shown for such code. Did you try adding `three` typings (`npm i @types/three`)?

Comment: @lena nope, since I am not using Typescript. It happens also for newly created project: install threejs, copy that two lines, open in webstorm and you have the error

Comment: recreated in 2018.3.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's fixed in 2019.1 (coming this quarter):

[image]

checked in WS-191.3749 (internal build, not published anywhere)

Comment: Do you have the JetBrains issue number for this? I'm experiencing a very similar issue in 2019.2 (WS-192.7142.35)

Comment: Figure I may as well link my post while I'm at it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62664252/use-typescript-declared-module-inside-own-declaration-file