# Use Typescript declared module inside own declaration file

Tags: javascript, typescript, declaration

My Javascript is running inside V8, which has a module `foo:bar/baz` available for import which is resolved by C++. I'm trying to write Typescript definitions for this module, so clients can interface with it in a type safe manner.

Here is the actual specification that I'm describing (in pseudo-code):

```
module 'foo:bar/baz' {
    ENUM1 // A magic object of unique but unknown value.
    ENUM2 // Same
    ENUM3 // Same
    doSomething(): MyClass
    // where MyClass has a member function that returns one of the above enums.
}
```

My goal is to provide type declarations for this module without exposing additional types or functionality that do not exist in the module.

Here is my declaration file:

```
declare module 'foo:bar/baz' {
    export const ENUM1: unique symbol;
    export const ENUM2: unique symbol;
    export const ENUM3: unique symbol;

    // Unexported because there is no MyEnum in the true module.
    export type MyEnum = typeof ENUM1 | typeof ENUM2 | typeof ENUM3;
    export function doSomething(): MyClass;
}

declare interface MyClass {
    member(): MyEnum;
}
```

And my usage of this module is:

```
import * as baz from 'foo:bar/baz';

/** @type MyClass */
const x = baz.doSomething();
```

The issue right now is that `MyEnum` is not available in the scope of `declare class MyClass` as it lives in the `foo:bar/baz` module. I've tried adding `import { MyEnum } from 'foo:bar/baz'` between the module and class declarations, but my linter says that module cannot be found.

If I change the declaration to be:

```
declare module 'foo:bar/baz' {
    export const ENUM1: unique symbol;
    export const ENUM2: unique symbol;
    export const ENUM3: unique symbol;

    export type MyEnum = typeof ENUM1 | typeof ENUM2 | typeof ENUM3;
    export function doSomething(): MyClass;

    interface MyClass {
        member(): MyEnum;
    }
}
```

Then `MyEnum` does resolve in the scope of `MyClass`, however, now my type checker does not recognize any methods on `x`, as there is no `MyClass` in the scope of my usage, only `baz.MyClass`.

If I change my annotation to `@type baz.MyClass`, then the type checker does show methods on `x` however now the assignment is invalid with the error `Initializer type MyClass is not assignable to variable type baz.MyClass`.

Two questions here:

1. Is this just a failure of the WebStorm type checker to properly recognize that these classes are the same type?
2. Is there a way around this? If I could change my module declaration to `declare module Baz`, then I could leave `declare class MyClass` outside the module and reference `MyEnum` instead as `Baz.MyEnum` and everything would resolve correctly. However, the module *must* be named `foo:bar/baz`. Is there a way I can dereference this module to the exported `MyEnum` member?

The only workaround I've been able to find is to use the second declaration mentioned and change my usage to:

```
import * as baz from 'foo:bar/baz';
import { MyClass } from 'foo:bar/baz';


/** @type MyClass */
const x = baz.doSomething();
```

This yields proper type resolution of `x` without a type error on the assignment. However, `foo:bar/baz` does not have a `MyClass`, as mentioned at the beginning, so my understanding is that this import would fail to resolve.

Comment: I don't see a reason why `MyClass` should not be part of the module. It's not a global. Yes, it needs to be an `interface` or `type` declaration, not a `class` declaration. I think your third snippet where you declare the `interface MyClass` inside the module should work, you only forgot to `export` the interface in there.

Comment: @Bergi If I do as you suggest, then I get an error from my linter `Initializer type MyClass is not assignable to variable type baz.MyClass` hence my question (1).

Comment: Hm, might this be [a Webstorm bug](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54238584/1048572)?

Comment: Seems likely, given that those two classes should be the same class. However, I'm running build `WS-192.7142.35` while that post claims the issue is fixed in `>=WS-191.3749`